# Bracket (Expected a declaration)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to the community but I need help concerning on brackets expecting a declaration and a user defined function not being found

```
//Problem 1.1
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int intPow(int base, int exponent); // this one has a green line
int main() {
    int Base, Expo,final;
    cout << "Enter Base value:";
    cin >> Base;
    cout << "Enter Exponent Value";
    cin >> Expo;
    final = intPow(Base, Expo);
    cout << "Base Exponent of given value:" << intPow;
    system("pause");
}
int intPow(int base, int exponent);//and this got a greenline to, telling me that It is not found
{ //and this one got a redline expecting me to put a declaration
    for (int a = 0; a <= Expo; a++)
        return intPow;
}
```

I am coding this on Visual Studio 2017 C++
Thank you for the help

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of your "green line".

Comment: Furthermore, the implementation of your function intPow not only won't compile. It's also quite wrong.

Comment: holy smokes it's gone, apparently the one I am following in our school module must've been from a different program. Thank you for the fix!

Comment: I'm trying to do a user defined function, am I missing something? The output that I am trying to do is entering a base value digit with the exponential digit then it will be showed like this (4,3)= 4*4*4

Comment: I posted an answer that corrects the function implementation.

Comment: @Gab Three answers for a simple typo, really?? Delete that question please and stop wasting everyone's time here.

Comment: sorry, I really am new to this type of thing, one of our modules wasn't clear enough for me to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the answer to the original question, just a correction of the function implementation:
It does not check for arithmetic overflow though. So, `intPow(10, 100)` will fail. Also a negative exponent will fail (returning 1 for any negative value).

```
int intPow(int base, int exponent)
{
  int result = 1;
  for (int a = 0; a < exponent; a++) // loop 'exponent' times
    result *= base;
  return result;
}
```

The original implementation has some problems:

- The `Expo` variable is defined within the main function
  and therefore not visible within this function
- The for-loop runs once too often
- Within the for-loop, the function returns calling the function itself once again (without parameters though)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I might have to delete this later also sorry for such a trivial mistake, The ones that were in our lessons are hella different compared to the actual codes you guys corrected to me. I think It's all good now

Answer (score 0):

First of all note that you are doing:

```
cout << "Base Exponent of given value:" << intPow;
```

instead of

```
cout << "Base Exponent of given value:" << final;
```

Now the problem you are describing is that when implementing the function it is expecting to find a block of code delimited by brackets right after the definition `int intPow(int base, int exponent)`. Instead you are putting a semicolonon:

Just do :

```
int intPow(int base, int exponent)//and this got a greenline to, telling me that It is not found
{ //and this one got a redline expecting me to put a declaration
    for (int a = 0; a <= Expo; a++)
        return intPow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I finally sort and used the functions and avoided some error thank you to @RobertKock and @FrancescoBoi.
The task given to me was to insert a base number and its exponents after that I should show the quantity of the exponents that was in the base kind of like this. 4,3 (4^3) = 4*4*4.
I almost had the code correctly, the only problem is the character "*" is following along the for loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int intPow(int digits, int exponent) 
        {
            int result = 1;
            for (int a = 0; a < exponent; a++)
                cout << digits<<"*";
                result = digits;
            return result;
        }
    int main()
        {
        int Base, Expo,final;
            cout << "Enter Base value:";
            cin >> Base;
            cout << "Enter Exponent Value:";
            cin >> Expo;
            final = intPow(Base, Expo);
            system("pause");
        }
```